# Cannot read property 'localeData' of undefined meteor.js

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar, momentjs, meteor-blaze

I am trying to use fullcalender.js but it is showing error

```js
 at getMomentLocaleData (rzymek_fullcalendar.js?  hash=d3abc7a76bbff89adf40aebd738c6d56c5cf0659:2586) 
 at locale (rzymek_fullcalendar.js?  hash=d3abc7a76bbff89adf40aebd738c6d56c5cf0659:2477) 
 at Object.defineProperty.value (rzymek_fullcalendar.js? hash=d3abc7a76bbff89adf40aebd738c6d56c5cf0659:2591) 
 at __webpack_require__ (rzymek_fullcalendar.js? hash=d3abc7a76bbff89adf40aebd738c6d56c5cf0659:62) 
 at Object.defineProperty.value (rzymek_fullcalendar.js?hash=d3abc7a76bbff89adf40aebd738c6d56c5cf0659:12531) 
 at __webpack_require__ (rzymek_fullcalendar.js? hash=d3abc7a76bbff89adf40aebd738c6d56c5cf0659:62) 
 at Object.defineProperty.value (rzymek_fullcalendar.js? hash=d3abc7a76bbff89adf40aebd738c6d56c5cf0659:7399) 
 at __webpack_require__ (rzymek_fullcalendar.js? hash=d3abc7a76bbff89adf40aebd738c6d56c5cf0659:62) 
 at Object.defineProperty.value (rzymek_fullcalendar.js?hash=d3abc7a76bbff89adf40aebd738c6d56c5cf0659:12141) hash=d3abc7a76bbff89adf40aebd738c6d56c5cf0659:62)
```

I have added packages jQuery and moment from atmospherejs.But still error in momentlocaleData function

Comment: I think this is something to do with the load order. You need to load momentjs and jquery BEFORE fullcalender.js.

Comment: In package.js right?

Comment: ```package.js``` is for all npm/node modules. Anything from atmosphere will show up in ```.meteor/packages```

Comment: Yes i have already added it in packages.Moment above it.Still getting error

Comment: And you've used [this](https://atmospherejs.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar) package for fullcalendar?